# Can Testdisk be used from the same Hard drive?

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

I have accidentally removed two partitions. I installed TestDisk and started Analysing to detect the lost partitions.

the lost partitions are in /dev/sda. my Ubuntu installation and TestDisk of course are also on /dev/sda. I want to recover the whole partitions not copy some data, which means I will have to write a new table. is this ok, both being on the same hard drive? or do I have to do it from a live session? this will need a new search and 4 more hours!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't change the partition table of a harddrive in use. Furthermore all partitions of a drive need to be unmounted before we can rescue partition tables on that drive.

This can easily done by booting a live system.

To prevent further data loss it is however **not recommended** to change the partitioning on a drive directly. If data matter we should perform partition recovery on an image of the drive, or at least rescue our data on an external drive before we change the partition layout.